# Google Earth Engine and Sentinel-2 L2A processing update

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, reflectance, sentinel-hub

As of 25-January-2022 ESA has [updated its processing baseline](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/processing-baseline) for Sentinel-2

Therefore, Sentinel-2 L2A Bottom of Atmosphere (BOA) reflectance (L2A_BOA) should be retrieved using L2A_BOAi = (L2A_DNi + BOA_ADD_OFFSETi) / QUANTIFICATION_VALUEi

Hence, any Sentinel-2 L2A retrieved after 25-January-2022 (which did not account for the change) will have somewhat incorrect values, usually lower than before.

From what I see, Google Earth Engine (GEE) did not account for the change (yet?), thus Sentinel-2 L2A from GEE should be treated differently before and after the change.

MY question is - Does GEE plan to account for the change, meaning that users can retrieve Sentinel-2 L2A data seamlessly before and after the change or GEE does not plan to do any changes

Comment: As of Feb 2, 2022 the Processing Baseline page says the "Date Introduced" for the change is "Forthcoming".  Do you have other information that indicates the change has already occurred?

Comment: Hi @TylerErickson - it is probably not up to date. Go to GEE and have a look at RGB (or better at NDVI) of some field before and after the January 25th, you'll see the difference, meaning that the change already occurred but GEE did not account for

Answer (score 3):

The harmonized sentinel-2 L2A collection is already on GEE now:

- https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR_HARMONIZED

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this directly on the GEE group, where is more likely you will get an answer from the GEE team: https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was told that the GEE team also monitor StackExchange for `Google-Earth-Engine` labels, and I think this might help others here

Comment: This answer seems fine to me (I'm on the EE team). We do monitor SE, but for urgent issues like this the group is a better place.